# Unable to verify on Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, evm

I built an ERC721a contract which I will leave here, I also deployed it to Rinkeby thanks to REMIX, I put all the constructor parameters and so far everything is normal.

When I want to verify the contract, it tells me that the ABI parameters of the transaction do not correspond, I have done everything, from redeploying the contract, using abi.hashex.org, searching for the abi of the transaction and the contract still cannot be verified.

In Remix it compiles well and without any errors and I want to know what could be happening to me because in 3 weeks I will go into production and I don't want to have any setbacks.

I have also compared the hex of the expected and the abi and they correspond totally, I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

The address of the contract is: `0x9d1292498C66d96AB30db9a2097935590DbB6310`

The transaction is: `0x94d6441abfe51553884532b7b5ad67b0ed8f85c9c2de647e9c2c4f1e0e357a9d`

Solidity compiler is: `0.8.12`

It has optimization set to 200

The contract is: `https://github.com/jcocano/Awkward-Skeleton-Club-NFT/blob/main/contracts/AwkwardSkeletonClub.sol`

Data in the constructor:

Address

```
["0xe7b1d253b811Ca3a845e31F1124aEa502Bf73347", "0x60D48A149057b8B1A1fbD24DEE041705976204EF"]
```

uint

```
[95.5]
```

bytes32

```
0x1436d3e718a6667fbe4a515a2e2c40d67461c5f0ad1af52e7129c103c9307d01
```

String

```
ipfs://QmRspyfoBCPTBpPSfMKXcDPvTt41KMoC3EKaAECMAiPpSY/
```

String

```
ipfs://QmQrEKPnkDTgNqejDZ59RSaxDSRBSpM5QQtBoMUfckUU2R/
```

Greetings and thank you very much!

Comment: Check out [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol) and [hardhat-etherscan](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html).

Comment: unfortunately I already use multi sol to separate the contracts and I still can't verify

Comment: solved with ETERSCAN - CONTRACT VERIFICATION plugin in Remix, thanks a lot for reading